# Парсинг страницы

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Доброго времени суток! Нужно забрать кое-какие данные с сайта, но выдает ошибку:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://whois.domaintools.com/195.90.131.231)
> [function.file-get-contents]: failed
> to open stream: HTTP request failed!
> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

страницу пытаюсь загрузить через simple_html_dom:

> $site =
> file_get_html("http://whois.domaintools.com/$ip");

как мне решить эту проблему?

Comment: Попробуйте получить тело страницы при помощи socket и потом уже передать в simple_dom_html, в сокет пишите заголовки какого-нибудь реального браузера

Comment: я пытался открыть через curl, но результат тот же 

>$ch = curl_init();
>  >curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://whois.domaintools.com/$ip");
>
>curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0    
>(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0');  
>  >curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER,"http://whois.domaintools.com/$ip");>  
>     
>curl_exec($ch);
> 
>curl_close($ch);

Comment: спасибо @ReinRaus - ваш скрипт мне все-таки помог

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получите. Распишитесь.

```
<pre><?
$headers="Host: whois.domaintools.com\r\nAccept: */*\r\nAccept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4\r\nAccept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.10 Chromium/17.0.963.79 Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11\r\n";
$sock=fsockopen('whois.domaintools.com', 80);
$query="GET /195.90.131.231 HTTP/1.0\r\n".$headers."\r\n\r\n";
fwrite($sock, $query);
$res="";
while (!feof($sock))
    $res.=fread($sock, 2048);
fclose($sock);
$sp=explode("\r\n\r\n", $res);
echo htmlspecialchars(gunzip($sp[1]))."\r\n";

function gunzip($zipped) {
      $offset = 0;
      if (substr($zipped,0,2) == "\x1f\x8b")
         $offset = 2;
      if (substr($zipped,$offset,1) == "\x08")  {
         return gzinflate(substr($zipped, $offset + 8));
      }
      return "Unknown Format";
}  
?></pre>
```

CURL и `file_get_contents` передают заголовки, которые в юзерагенте содержат PHP, а сайт видимо из-за этого юзерагента возвращает 403.

Comment: Да-да, для кого API писано... Или я уже придираюсь?

Comment: @klopp, ну автор хотел выдернуть текст из HTML- я ему дал пример как получить HTML, а то что он пошел неправильным путем- это его проблема.  
Вы подсказали ему правильный путь, а я помог пройти по неправильному :)

Comment: Ну, если подумать - чем больше кривоходящих, тем больше у нас зарплата :)

Comment: результат тот же

Comment: если вы сейчас откроете пример, увидите там сообщение:
>Thank you for using the DomainTools for your domain research.
>       To protect >domain registrants we limit the number of anonymous
>       whois lookups >that are allowed. We wish that you will continue
>       using our >service for domain information but ask that you
>       create and >log into a DomainTools account before doing
>       any more >lookups.

Comment: и кстати - я пытался разобраться в их API, просто на это не хватает моего знания англицкого

Comment: @woland, а вы самостоятельно прочитать это сообщение и сделать выводы не в состоянии?

Comment: я прочитал - и привел его просто для примера - количество анонимных запросов ограничено

Comment: Ну, это ваше дело - читать и думать, или упорствовать.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала обзаведитесь первой утилитой каждого пауковода: **wget**. Запустите, и увидите:

```
wget -S "http://whois.domaintools.com/195.90.131.231"
--17:54:15--  http://whois.domaintools.com/195.90.131.231
           => `195.90.131.231'
Resolving whois.domaintools.com... done.
Connecting to whois.domaintools.com[199.93.60.254]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
 1 HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
 2 Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
 3 Pragma: no-cache
 4 Set-Cookie: csrftoken=a8346261cd9fdd81fa9af22a80be95ca; path=/; domain=.domaintools.com
 5 Set-Cookie: dtsession=ak67m6mt66fn012ppi629vmdc3; expires=Tue, 11-Apr-2023 13:54:15 GMT; path=/; domain=.domaintools.com
 6 Content-Type: text/html
 7 Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
 8 Server: lighttpd/1.4.30
 9 Date: Sat, 13 Apr 2013 13:54:16 GMT
10 Connection: close
```

17:54:16 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

Подумайте.

А лучше - не маяться дурью, а прочитать про API domaintools.com, там всё очень подробно расписано. В качестве домашнего упражнения предлагаю найти ссылку на документацию на их сайте. Если у вас это займёт больше двух кликов и 10 секунд - пичалька...